# Cannot connect to web service by jquery when it is at different folder

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I have created 1 application where I will call all the functions written as web service by jquery.... but when services and the aspx pages are in different folder then I am unable to call them. Please help. Below is my jquery code-

```
        function Save() {
        var leads = {};
        leads.name = $('#name').val();
        leads.companyname = $('#companyname').val();
        leads.email = $('#email').val();
        leads.phone = $('#phone').val();
        leads.designation = $('#designation').val();
        leads.lead_status = $('#lead_status').val();
        leads.oppor_amt = $('#oppoerunity_amt').val();
        leads.assigned_user = $('#user').val();
        leads.title = $('#title').val();
        leads.lastname = $('#lname').val();
        leads.account = $('#acc').val();
        leads.website = $('#ws').val();
        leads.lead_source = $('#source').val();
        leads.lead_campaign = $('#Text1').val();
        leads.lead_address = $('#address').val();
        leads.leaddesc = $('#Text3').val();
        leads.team = $('#team').val();
        leads.createddt = $('#crdt').val();

        //alert('hello world')

        $.ajax({
            url: '../../WebService/Opportunity/OpportunityService.asmx/Insert',// I cant be able to call this Insert function
            method: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            data: '{lead:' + JSON.stringify(leads) + '}',
            success: function () {
                alert('Saved');
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
        grid.reload();

    }
```

Comment: change the path to your insert to the new path

Comment: your url must be wrong that is that issue ...I suggest launch service and get url ex. http://localhost:8080/servicename

Comment: how can I get the right URL of the service